# How to send data- to ng-click function in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-ng-click

```
<td>
  <select ng-options="user.username as user.username for user in dptUsers" 
    ng-model="newResponsible" data-ticketID='{{ticket._id}}' 
    ng-click='editResponsible(newResponsible, <<<<>>>>)'>
                                 {{user.username}}
  </select> 
</td>
```

How can I pass my data-ticketID into my editResponsible(a, b) function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass that variable directly in `ng-click`

```
ng-click='editResponsible(newResponsible, ticket._id)'
```

Comment: Ohhh, man! I love you!
I was thinking that it would not work because of my ng-repeat. But it worked! Problem solved. Thanks again.

Comment: @RodrigoSouza Glad to help you..Thanks :)